# Add a UIView at specific coordinates to a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, annotations, mkmapview

I want to add a UIView to fixed coordinates on the mapview like a annotation. To be more specific the UIView should stay fixed at these coordinates on the mapview when the mapview is in interaction (moving, zooming, etc.) exactly the same like a annotation does it.

I tried to solve it with MKMapPoint but without success.

Hope someone has a tipp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to use custom annotatin view. There is an answer for that question. I dont think you can use a UIView as you described.

[How to create Custom MKAnnotationView and custom annotation title and subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle)