# MKMapView custom pins according to the boolean value

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I have MKMap with around 190 custom pins. I would like to change pin image according to the boolean values. But I have made static boolean and in -(void)Map, I get data from Parse and also all boolean values. When I use If/Else in delegate method for custom pins, all booleans went FALSE.

```
-(void)Map{
    CLLocation *userLoc = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;

    NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude);

    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *title = [self.itemss valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSMutableArray *subtitle = [self.itemss valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    NSMutableArray *latitude = [self.itemss valueForKey:@"Lati"];
    NSMutableArray *longitude = [self.itemss valueForKey:@"Long"];
    NSMutableArray *gold = [self.itemss valueForKey:@"clubPurchased"];


    NSLog(@"%@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"%@", longitude);

    for (int i = 0; i < [title count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)title.count);

        double lat = [[latitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        double lng = [[longitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        NSString *T = [title objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *TT = [subtitle objectAtIndex:i];

         mine = [[gold objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"BOOL:%hhd", mine);



        CLLocation *towerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng];
        [annotations addObject:towerLocation];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[annotations lastObject] coordinate];

        PlacePin * myAnnotation1=[[PlacePin alloc] init];

        myAnnotation1.coordinate=coord;
        myAnnotation1.title=T;
        myAnnotation1.subtitle=TT;

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        }



}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"welcome into the map view annotation");

    // if it's the user location, just return nil.


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];



    if (mine){
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Iconn"];
       NSLog(@"TRUE");


    } else {
       NSLog(@"FALSE");

        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Iconn_gold"];


    }
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;



    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;


    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In -(void)Map, the `mine` value was changed in the for-loop and it registered a value of the last item in the loop (which is most probably false).

In `viewForAnnotation`, `mine` value wasn't changing for each annotation, thus you get all false when the annotations are displayed.

You will need to save `mine` value to your custom annotation `PlacePin` in -(void)Map for each item (just like `title` and `subtitle`) and retrieve the value in `viewForAnnotation` for the if-else statement.

Also, you may not be accessing your custom annotations correctly in `viewForAnnotation`, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle).

**Edit 2:**

I believe `PlacePin` is your custom annotation. In PlacePin.h file,

```
@interface PlacePin : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
// Add this line
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *mine;
```

In - (void)Map,

```
PlacePin * myAnnotation1=[[PlacePin alloc] init];

myAnnotation1.coordinate=coord;
myAnnotation1.title=T;
myAnnotation1.subtitle=TT;
// Save the boolean value here
myAnnotation1.mine=[gold objectAtIndex:i];
```

In viewForAnnotation, try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlacePin class]])
    {
        PlacePin *placePin = (PlacePin *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView* pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"AnnotationIdentifier"];

        if(pinView)
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        else
        {
            // Edit 2: Note this line!!
            pinView = placePin.annotationView;
        }
        // Use this to check instead
        if ([pinView.mine boolValue])
        {
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Iconn"];
            NSLog(@"TRUE");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"FALSE");
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Iconn_gold"];
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I remade it by the post you suggested but by saving mine value you mean to save with NSUserDefaults? Because I have no idea how to save it.

Comment: See my edit. (I am typing this outside XCode, let me know if there is error.)

Comment: The if/else in viewForAnnotation is unable to find me mine property(`if ([pinView.mine boolValue])`)

Comment: adding `PlacePin *placepin = (PlacePin *)annotation;` fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: Glad that you figured out that line, I forgot about that. Do amend the second line that I added too.