# iOS9 Popover using modal on a MapView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, ios9

I have a question regarding how to do a popover in iOS9. I have been working on trying to get a popover to display over a MapView using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle) question and answer by `Rob`. However, using a `UIPopoverController` was depreciated and now xCode is telling me...

> Popovers are now implemented using UIViewController presentations. Use modal presentation style UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController

However, I have not been able to figure out how to exactly do that and I would hope that someone else knows how to implement a popover using iOS9.

Here is my code so far.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let annoation = view.annotation!
    mapView.deselectAnnotation(annoation, animated: false)
    let popupController  = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapPopupViewController") as! PopupAnnotationViewController
    popupController.annotation = annoation

    //WHAT TO DO NOW?

}
```