# How to show a UIView just above the MKpointAnnotation Pin

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpointannotation

I want to show a UIView just above the pin location and if the user moves around the map the UIView should remain above the pin location. I dont want to use the callout bubble. Is there any other way?

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38741017/6433023

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 9 we have a new property named detailCalloutAccessoryView

You can create a view and set as

```
annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = tempView
```

Please check the link to get more details

[MapKit iOS 9 detailCalloutAccessoryView usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581049/mapkit-ios-9-detailcalloutaccessoryview-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
    else if (annotation is YourAnnotationClassHere) {
        let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        if annotationView {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation
        }
        else {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false
        // set to YES if using customized rendition of standard callout; set to NO if creating your own callout from scratch
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "your-image-here.png")!
        return annotationView
    }

    return nil
}
```

That's mainly what you need for that to work. This is a swift version of this answer right here: [How to create Custom MKAnnotationView and custom annotation title and subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle)

Hope it helped!!!

Comment: Since you haven't posted any of your code, this is the only way I can help you