# how to make button (in annotationView map) open different links on each new pin

Tags: button, mkannotationview

*Question is : How can i make the button (when pressed) open the link witch corresponds to the chosen shop on the pin?

*I have an array of shops (for pins) (i created a class  for it, and a class for pinAnnotation)*

*here i am creating  button and pin image*

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

```
    let identifier = "annotationReusedId"
    var anView = myMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
```

if anView == nil {

```
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

    } else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    anView!.image = UIImage(named: "upcycled")
    anView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
    anView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    anView!.canShowCallout = true
    let rightButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
    rightButton.tag = annotation.hash
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(openLinkInstagram), for: .touchUpInside)

    //anView!.animatesDrop = true
    anView!.canShowCallout = true
    anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
    return anView
}
```

here is func for openning link

func openLinkInstagram() {
    }

Comment: chec kout this answer [How to create Custom MKAnnotationView and custom annotation title and subtitle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle) it should help to solve you problem

Comment: Check out this answer [How to create Custom MKAnnotationView and custom annotation title and subtitle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252764/how-to-create-custom-mkannotationview-and-custom-annotation-title-and-subtitle) should help.